# Split Column (Delimit) in Pandas DataFrame ; columns same length as key error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has a column, called "Financial Week Name", that has something like 'week 17' for each financial week.

```
  Financial Week Name   Day Part
    week 0          Breakfast
    week 0          Lunch
    week 0          Dinner
    week 1          Breakfast
    week 1          Lunch
```

The problem is that I can't sort these from smallest to largest. My thought was to hack out anything after the space after the word 'week'; essentially delimiting. I added an empty column (named 'weekNo') to the dataframe, and then tried to use the .str.split method to push the numbers in to the newly created column:

```
 df[['Financial Week Name', 'weekNo']] = df['Financial Week Name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

but got the following error:

```
" ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"
```

I'm not sure how get the number value from the end the string "week x" to get to a separate column, and have tried to use .iloc to unsuccessfully slice out the values. I'm pretty stumped; Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would like to sort chronologically, by the financial week number.

Answer (score 0):

Working off the last comment you might have an extra space somewhere in your `Financial Week Name` column.
For example

```
  Financial Week Name   Day Part
    week 0          Breakfast
    week 0          Lunch
    week 0          Dinner
    week 1          Breakfast
    week  1         Lunch
```

That last entry will cause the split function to produce a row with 3 elements, and your passing it to 2 columns hence

```
" ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"
```

I suggest you just extract numbers from that column

```
df['weekNo'] = df['Financial Week Name'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case I had wrongly put quotes in column name :

```
Corrected : no_match_df[['matched_url', 'cosine_score', 'jaccard_score', 'score', 'match_type']]
Mistake : no_match_df[['matched_url', 'cosine_score', 'jaccard_score', 'score', 'match_type']]
```

Spent almost 3 hours to figure out.

Comment: Looks like _Corrected_ equals _Mistake_?